# Access Google My Business Statistics with API in php

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

I manage approximately 200 Google My business accounts, all being owned under an email XXX@YYY.com
I would like to use the Google My Business API using a PHP SDK to retrieve all types of stats regarding each accounts (ie. view per timeframe, view through map, view through SERP, etc...).

I did get the authorization to use the Google My Business API and I downloaded the php SDK: https://developers.google.com/my-business/samples/google-api-services-mybusiness-v4p9-php-rev-20210224-1.zip?hl=fr

I also created a service account (which I'm really not familiar with) in order to auth with the library.

Now here is my code :

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    // set the service account json file location manually
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__.'/../global/yyyyy-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.json');
    $client->setApplicationName("yyyyyb");
    // set the scope to access GMBs
    $client->setScopes([
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage"
    ]);



    $this->client = $client;


    $mybusinessService = new Google_Service_Mybusiness($client);



    $accounts = $mybusinessService->accounts;
    $accountsList = $accounts->listAccounts()->getAccounts();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($accountsList);
    echo "</pre>";
    $locationNames = array("Paris");
    $insightReqObj = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_ReportLocationInsightsRequest();


    $insightReqObj->setLocationNames($locationNames);
    $basicReqObj = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_BasicMetricsRequest();
    // datetime range is mandatory
    // TODO :: validate to not allow more than 18 months difference
    $timeRangObj = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_TimeRange();
    $timeRangObj->setStartTime("2020-01-01T15:01:23Z");
    $timeRangObj->setEndTime("2021-01-11T15:01:23Z");

    $metricReqObj = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_MetricRequest();
    $metricReqObj->setMetric('ALL');

    $basicReqObj->setMetricRequests(array($metricReqObj));
    $basicReqObj->setTimeRange($timeRangObj);
    $insightReqObj->setBasicRequest($basicReqObj);
    $allInsights = $mybusinessService->accounts_locations->reportInsights("accounts/XXXXXXXX",$insightReqObj);
   
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($allInsights);
    echo "</pre>";
```

There are two issues :

- When I print the accountlist, I only find information about my service account, I was expecting a list of all the accounts managed by my email : XXX@YYY.com ; I realise that it makes no sense since I don't even know how to grant the service account access to the My Business account managed by this email.
- Also AllInsignt generate an error :
  [image: Text]

How can I access the statistics of all the accounts managed by my Gmail account : XXX@YYY.com ?